# VS Code Integrated terminal does not execute commands from extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ideally, the integrated VS Code terminal, depending on the context, the type of the folder and the extension, executes some commands. For example, when opening a folder containing a Python virtual environment in VS code, the environment is recognized and activated (by the python extension) by default when opening a new integrated terminal instance (situation 1). This is done by running some command similar to `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`.

Or, when using the ROS extension to debug nodes, selecting "Start Debugging (F5)" uses the `launch.json` file to start some nodes and finally starts debugging the desired code. To do so also, there is some command that is executed (also by he ROS extension, I assume) in the integrated terminal (situation 2) to start the debugging process. In case of debugging ROS nodes, the command usually looks something like `/usr/bin/env /bin/sh /tmp/someFileName`.

But, unfortunately, both of the above mentioned situations fail. I believe this happens because while the extension tries to run these two commands within their respective integrated terminals, the commands do not actually get executed in either situation. Instead, these commands are printed on the top of the terminal, but the state of the terminal is unchanged (as opposed to when the commands would have been executed, in which case depending on the commands some actions are performed). Here are two images to show what I mean. Top, situation 1 and bottom, situation 2.

[image: Python extension sourcing the virtual environment]

[image: ROS extension trying to debug the node]

The fact that these two commands are printed on top of the terminal as soon as the a new terminal instance is opened tells me that the extension tries to execute them, but they do not work for some unknown reasons.

Just to be clear, both of them are run in a seperate VC Code window, they have nothing to do with each other. When I manually run both the commands in their respective terminals I do get the desired results.

Now, I am unsure exactly how to name this issue. But I think this is surely an issue with the integrated terminal, and not a problem of the extensions. I am not sure how one could reproduce this problem.

I did a clean reinstall of VS code by deleting `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`. Because I am using this on WSL, there is only `~/.vscode-server` on the ubuntu side. I manually uninstalled all extensions on WSL but did not delete this folder, in fear of breaking something. The problem still persisted. I have also created an issue on the [VS Code GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158573#issue-1344247118) with nearly the same information.

I am unsure if this is a bug or is there something wrong with my settings. Does anyone know how I could fix this? For smaller use-cases I can still manually enter the command in the terminal. But I am trying to debug a ROS application with nearly 10 different terminals opening up and I cannot be manually entering the command each time to restart the process.

Please let me know if you need any more information. Many thanks in advance.

Edit: both edits to frame the question properly.

Comment: still unclear what the problem is? You only have the problem when you work remote on a WSL and NO problem when working local?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay I realize now that I did not really frame a proper question in the end. Now I have edited the question.

Comment: Also, to answer your question. I am not working local. Everything that I need is in WSL. But, I would assume this has nothing to do with that. Maybe I need to change some settings in VS Code, maybe this is a common bug that I am unable to figure out. I would just like to be pointed in a direction.

Comment: the problem with the question is: `But, unfortunately, it is unable to do these because while the extension probably tries to run this command with the terminal, the terminal does not actually run them`. Explain what is `it`, `these`, `them`, `this`, not explain but rewrite with the actual nouns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience with my bad explanation and your suggestions. I have edited the question to the best of my knowledge. Please let me know if it understandable now. Thanks once again for all your help.

Comment: if you start the whole stuff on WSL does it work, work local on WSL? Is the terminal shown a terminal on WSL. Does it work if you have a venv in a local workspace? Does it work if you use `vscode-insiders` with only the Python extension? I work with venv's local and never had such a problem. Maybe somebody in the VSC team can explain why the command is shown but not executed.

Comment: This also happens to me in macOS. I did some debugging in VSCode and it turns out that the way extension terminal commands work is that they open a new terminal window providing the command that they want to execute but the integrated terminal does not wait for the first prompt and therefore the text in the sent to the new terminal gets eaten or partially eaten by the shell. I do believe this is a matter of timeouts caused by either the dotfiles or a slow network connection. I think I even saw a message saying that the terminal was taking too long to launch and vscode expected less than 100ms

Answer (score 1):

Although not related to WSL, I dug a little deeper today as to why in my case the extension commands were not being executed or were being chopped.

I'm an iTerm2 user. iTerm2 has something called Shell Integrations, which allow iTerm to behave differently under certain circumstances, for example, adding markers to each prompt or coloring output with certain text (e.g. WARNING or ERROR)

From time to time, I also use the VSCode Integrated Terminal, which recently added support for reporting whether the previous command errored out with an indicator on the gutter of the Integrated Terminal panel using the exit code.

iTerm can do something similar but the shell integrations mess up completely the VSCode functionality and therefore I changed my `.bashrc` file to detect if the terminal emulator was iTerm2 or not (which can be done with the `it2check` utility of iTerm2) so that it only sourced the shell integrations if I was using iTerm2.

The problem is that `it2check` "eats" some STDIN bytes using `dd`, specifically, until it finds an `n` so that it can obtain the name of the emulator. This of course chops the commands on the STDIN until the first `n` and makes VSCode Extension Terminal commands unusable

The workaround I came up with is to use the value of "$TERM_PROGRAM" as means to distinguish between the different programs. The only caveat is that the value won't be passed if you're inside of a `tmux` session or similar, but I can live with that.

In your case, I'd check for any process that is either not passing the STDIN to the WSL process or any dot files or shell profile scripts eating up the STDIN they receive.

I suspect that the real problem is that the local process doesn't relay the STDIN contents to the WSL and as a workaround you may try to create a VSCode Integrated Terminal profile that uses SSH to connect to the WSL host so that the STDIN is preserved